# PowerShell "WARNING: The prediction 'ListView' is temporarily disabled because the current window size of the console is too small"

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2022, windows-terminal

Every time I open the integrated terminal in VS Code, there is always a warning like this:

> WARNING: The prediction 'ListView' is temporarily disabled because the current window size of the console is too small. To use the
> 'ListView', please make sure the 'WindowWidth' is not less than '54' and the 'WindowHeight' is not less than '15'.

Why does this warning happen? What does it mean? How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: I get this too in Visual Studio 2022 preview

Comment: This sounds like something in your psreadline configuration. Did you do anything to customize pwsh? Like, set `Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionViewStyle ListView` in your profile?

Comment: @zadjii Yes, I did that. Because I added Predictive IntelliSense to PowerShell Prompt with PSReadline. I followed the tutorial from here: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/adding-predictive-intellisense-to-my-windows-terminal-powershell-prompt-with-psreadline

Answer (score 0):

This is a PowerShell warning- specifically from [PSReadLine](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine), which implements the CLI-editing features for PowerShell v3 and up. The related source code can be found [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/blob/v2.2.6/PSReadLine/PSReadLineResources.Designer.cs#L2062) in the `WindowSizeTooSmallForListView` property of the `PSReadLineResources` class. "Predictions" are the autocomplete feature (I presume), and the "Prediction list view" is a... list view of predictions.

The error message is mostly pretty self explanatory. The only murky part might be units. I'm pretty sure the units of "WindowWidth" and "WindowHeight" are in units of "character cells" (in windows console terminology).

I'm personally not aware of a way silence the warning (I don't know much about PSReadLine), so all I can think of to make the warning stop is to satisfy its constraint: You could increase the size of your Integrated Terminal Panel (which might require increasing the size of your VS Code window), or you could try some... creative ways of increasing the character cell dimensions by picking different fonts (the `terminal.integrated.fontFamily` setting), or changing the integrated terminal font size (the `terminal.integrated.fontSize` setting).

Or perhaps you can change your `PredictionViewStyle` option to `InlineView` instead of `ListView`.

Answer (score -1):

You can suppress this warning message by changing the value of the `$WarningPreference` variable to `"SilentlyContinue"`.

To start, edit your PowerShell profile script. You can find its location using the `$PROFILE` variable.

Then add the following line and save the changes.

```
$WarningPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
```

Once added, restart the PowerShell session or reload the profile.

```
. $PROFILE
```

Comment: This 'answer' is missing an explanation, which can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.3#warningpreference