# Installing a local unpackaged VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to install a custom version of a VSCode extension without packaging it into a .vsix file. I've copied an existing extension in `~/.vscode-server/extensions/original-extension` to `~/.vscode-server/extensions/my-custom-extension` with my modifications, but VSCode doesn't seem to detect that it's there: it's not in the Extensions sidebar after reloading the window, etc.

I've also tried and failed to install the custom extension locally in case it was something specific to the remote setup (copying into `~/.vscode/extensions` and running VSCode locally), so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

From these (possibly outdated) docs, it seems like side-loading by just copying into the `extensions` folder should work: https://vscode-docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extensions/install-extension/#sharing-privately-with-others-side-loading . Is there a way to get VSCode to detect my extensions folder? What am I missing?

Comment: You need to refer to information under `code.visualstudio.com`, not any other domains.

Comment: Gotcha. I wasn't able to find any info about this on the official docs either.

Comment: "I wasn't able to find any info about this on the official docs either" is a good sign that this is not a supported feature.

Comment: Yes, I'm not surprised that this isn't a common/well-supported use case. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this regardless — it seems like it could be possible, since I'm adding an extensions directory of the same format and in the same location as the other officially-installed extensions.

Comment: this seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/73864754/11107541